# Stopping sounds looping in J2ME

Tags: audio, java-me

I am currently adding sound to my Rock, Paper, Scissors J2ME app. At the moment I can get the sound to play, but it plays in a continuous loop which will not stop. I have called `stop();` and this does not seem to help. Below is the code I have used to create the sound:

```
    private void playSound(String sound)

    {
        try{

            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(sound+".wav");
            Player p = Manager.createPlayer(in, "audio/x-wav");
            p.start();
            p.stop();

            //System.out.println("sound playing...");

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Sound error:" + e);
        }

    }
```

How can I make the sound stop?

Comment: "stop() does not seem to help" - how exactly? what do you get when you run the code you posted (`p.start();p.stop();`)? is there a sound? are you getting exception? or something else?

Comment: i am getting a sounds that just keeps playing over and over....i thought that stop() would have stopped it playing. i only want the sound to play once you see

Comment: and what is there in console? I assume you debug with emulator right? if yes, why did you commented `System.out.println("sound playing...");`?

Comment: i have uncommneted it now. the sound plays fine!! all i am asking is how to i get it to stop looping round, as the p.stop(); deosnt seem to be stopping the sound

Comment: so what's there in console? I understand that you need sound stop - ask about that to help you figure what's going wrong in your code

Comment: i call playSound like this case STATE_WON:
                String sound1 = "winBeep";
                playSound(sound1);
                paintWon(g, w, h);
                repaint();
                break;

Comment: that is the entire code for my sounds......am i missing something? x

Comment: do you see "sound playing..." printed to emulator console when you run your code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using [MMAPI](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/index.html) and [MIDP](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) API. If that's the case then the way you use to test how `stop` works is unlikely to work as you expect. Look:

```
    p.start();
    p.stop();
```

If you invoke stop immediately after start, there is a chance that [Player](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/mm/jsr135/javax/microedition/media/Player.html) will ignore it because it is not yet in state ready to be stopped.

If you want to learn how stop works, add a command to stop to the screen and invoke it *after* you hear the sound playing. At that moment it is reasonable to expect player to be in the state ready to stop.